# indexof exactvalue match

Tags: c#

environment: microsoft visual studio 2008 c#

How do I get the index of a whole word found in a string

```
string dateStringsToValidate = "birthdatecake||birthdate||other||strings";
string testValue = "birthdate";

var result = dateStringsToValidate.IndexOf(testValue);
```

It doesn't have to be the way i did it either, for example, would it be better to use regular expressions or other methods?

**Update:**
The word is birthdate not birthdatecake. it doesn't have to retrieve the match but the index should find the right word. i don't think IndexOf is what i'm looking for then. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: He means something like 'whole word' match.

Comment: The simplest solution for your exact test case is to change your testValue to "birthdate|", but I think you want a more flexible solution than that. You need to define your problem a little more exactly.

Comment: @MattBurland if you just append '|' you won't be able to match against the last word, and you could potentially match the end of something else, i.e. `||notarealbirthdate||` matches `birthdate|`

Comment: @Servy: Yes, I know, that's why I said it was the simplest solution for the OP's *exact* test case. It wasn't supposed to be a generic solution because we don't have enough information in the definition of the problem. You could fix both those problems by searching for "|birthdate|" and appending a "|" to the beginning and end of your string before searching and then remembering to adjust the index afterwards. But again, it's probably not the solution they really want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use regular expressions for this

```
  string dateStringsToValidate = "birthdatecake||birthdate||other||strings";
  string testValue = "strings";
  var result = WholeWordIndexOf(dateStringsToValidate, testValue);

// ...

public int WholeWordIndexOf(string source, string word, bool ignoreCase = false)
{
  string testValue = "\\W?(" + word + ")\\W?";

  var regex = new Regex(testValue, ignoreCase ? 
         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : 
         RegexOptions.None);

  var match = regex.Match(source);
  return match.Captures.Count == 0 ? -1 : match.Groups[0].Index;
}
```

Learn more about regex options in c# [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Another option, depending on your needs, is to split the string (as I see you have some delimiters). Please note the index returned by the this option is the index by word count, not character count (In this case, 1, as C# has zero based arrays).

```
  string dateStringsToValidate = "birthdatecake||birthdate||other||strings";
  var split = dateStringsToValidate.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  string testValue = "birthdate";
  var result = split.ToList().IndexOf(testValue);
```

Comment: Because I think he wants the whole word

Comment: The second method will return the index of the string match in the split list, not in the source string..

Comment: @AdrianIftode I added some context to the 2nd option to clarify that. Thank you.

Comment: @payo: I don't think your second solution would actually work. IndexOf in the last line will give you the index in the array after the split, not the index in the original string. The first solution should work however. - edit: nevermind, Adrian beat me too it!

Comment: Splitting the string would be best if you're going to perform lots of these searches on the same string, as you can put the split strings into a dictionary or other structure that can be effectively searched.  If you're just searching the once it's a net loss to parse it out like that.

Comment: I actually had a bug with no match, as zero is returned. The update I just made corrects that.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* deal with the exact index in the given string, then this is of little use to you.  If you just want to find the best match in the string, this could work for you.

```
var dateStringsToValidate = "birthdatecake||birthdate||other||strings";
var toFind = "birthdate";

var splitDateStrings = dateStringsToValidate.Split(new[] {"||"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var best = splitDateStrings
    .Where(s => s.Contains(toFind))
    .OrderBy(s => s.Length*1.0/toFind.Length) // a metric to define "best match"
    .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(best);
```